# Another class's static function does not modify the reference passed in

Tags: java

Just got really confused why this is happening:

```
public class OneClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1111");
        AnotherClass.updateParameter(sb);
        System.out.print(sb);
    }
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public static void updateParameter(StringBuilder args) {
        args.append("2222");
    }
}

Output: 1111
```

Can anyone please explain, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you show doesn't have the behaviour you describe (instead, it prints `11112222`).

The most likely explanation is that you're not running the code you think you're running (e.g. you have multiple different copies of `AnotherClass`, or you forgot to save the file or to recompile it etc)